# Linearity Of A Function

Tags: functions

I understand that the linearity of a function is determined by the degree of the polynomial but I was unsure whether the modulus operator changes this?

Is $f(x) = N \mod x$ a linear function if $N$ and $x$ are integers?

As in:

$f(x) = 17 \mod x$

Comment: That would not be a well defined function. What is $17 \mod 1.23$?

Comment: @PeterT.off Surely OP wants the domain $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$?

Comment: @anon I think it is normal to note $x$ a real number. Anyways, it would not be a function like polynomials and linear functions, which the OP mentions, which are usually $\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think the clarification would change the answer.  Both N and x are integers.  N is just another variable.  It is linear?

Comment: No.  $f(4) = 17 \mod 4 = 1$ but $f(2) + f(2) = 17 \mod 2 + 17 \mod 2 = 2$.

Comment: if $f(x)=mx+b$, and $m=17$ and $b=3$.  Then $f(4)=71$, and $f(2)=37$, and $f(2)+f(2)=74$.  $74$ not equal $71$, but $f(x)$ is definitively linear.

Comment: @PeterT.off , $17\ mod\ 1.23\ =\ 1.01$ .  $17-1.01\ =\ 15.99.\ \ \ 15.99/1.23\ =\ 13$

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide what you mean by linear before you can answer this question. The function $f(x)=mx+b$, which you call "definitively linear", satisfies $$f(r-s)-2f(r)+f(r+s)=0$$ for all $r,s$. The function $f(x)=17$ reduced modulo $x$ doesn't: $$f(2)-2f(3)+f(4)=1-4+1=-2\ne0$$ If you want to call it linear, go ahead, but beware that it won't do most of the things that you might expect linear functions to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is linear over any subset of the domain of the form $(a,a+17)$, where $a$ is where the $ 17 \mod a = 0$.